# how to stop animate a div on keydown to stop at end of the screen

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have given a function to arrow keys to move a div on keydwn  -- position left =+50, top =+50 like so...

how i can make it stop when it reaches end of the screen...

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
switch (e.which) {
case 37:
    $('#player').stop().animate({
        left: '-=50'

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch (e.which) {
        case 37:
            var left = parseInt( $('#player').css('left'), 10),
                ani  = left > 50 ? 50 : left;

            if (ani > 0) {
                $('#player').stop().animate({
                    left: '-='+ani
                });
            }
        break;
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pb5FF/)

Comment: @AtalShrivastava - What "all keys", there is just one key targeted ?

Comment: how i can add this function for all four keys

Comment: if the same i use for case 38, case 39, case 40

Comment: The code in your question is only for 37, and it animates left, so this checks if the left offset is zero, to use it for right, top etc. you have to rewrite it completely for those offsets, it won't just magically work for everything.

Comment: it has problem at the top left corner of the screen. here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/atalshrivastava/ewnq9/1/